# ¿Cómo insertar masivamente en oracle a partir de una cadena de manera eficiente?

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, update

Buen día. Quisiera saber cual es la manera más eficiente de poder insertar/actualizar en una tabla a partir de una cadena:

Cadena de ejemplo:

```
Cadena:='111;Madrid|222;Espana|333;Colombia...';
```

Cada grupo de registros se separa con `|` (pipe) y su contenido con `;` (punto y coma)

En una tabla con campos

```
Codigo|Pais
```

La idea es que que a partir de la cadena se pueda hacer una inserción/actualización masiva de estos datos, sin tener que hacer un for que recorra cada dato y por ende realizar n inserts, lo cual es poco eficiente.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo (
    Cadena  VARCHAR(1000)
);

INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Cadena)
VALUES  ('111;Madrid|222;Espana|333;Colombia');

SELECT regexp_substr(Cadena, '[^;]+', 1, 1) Codigo,
       regexp_substr(Cadena, '[^;]+', 1, 2) Pais
       FROM (SELECT regexp_substr(Cadena, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) Cadena
                    FROM Ejemplo
                    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(Cadena, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
             );

drop table Ejemplo;
```

Puedes usar [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) para detectar los separadores, primero los pipes y luego el punto y coma. Para poder "procesar" indefinidamente la cadena hacemos uso de [Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) mediante `CONNECT BY`

Comment: Aunque la respuesta es adecuada para el número de posibles registros (países) y número de atributos (código y país), no creo que este aproach sea adecuado para cargar *masivamente* en un escenario real (me refiero a cargas de miles de registros y con varios atributos). ¿Es correcto? Lo digo por el máximo tamaño que un VARCHAR / VARCHAR2 puede adquirir al ser insertado en una tabla.

Comment: @Corpex, sin duda un `VARCHAR` tiene un límite de 4000 bytes.